# PHP COM Component. How to use it to get the generated HTML by the Browser?

Tags: php, html, parsing, com

I need to parse a webpage that is generated by JavaScript. I have been investigating the PHP COM Component and I think is this what I need to get the HTML generated by the browser.

My problem is that I can't find how to access the HTML generated by the browser

```
<?php
$browser = new COM("InternetExplorer.Application");
$browser->navigate("http://www.yahoo.com");
$browser->Visible = true;
$browser->Width = 700;
$browser->height = 380;
?>
```

Whit this I'm able to open the browser. Now... how can I go to links and save the HTML generated by the browser?

Can someone give me a clue on this?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) makes me think that `$browser->Document` would contain the page; see the comment @André left.

Note that it looks like you can check the manual for the invoked .Net object for questions like this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I got an error if I try: "$browser->document;"

Comment: Did you try to access the property with a capital letter, as in my answer? This is what it says in the manual; and let's be honest, you're using .Net here, which uses caps for _everything_.

Comment: You could also try to `var_dump` the browser variable, to see what it contains (and if it contains the text somewhere).